# Dart: New project in my command palette does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run ctrl + shift + p to navigate into Dart: New project, after clicking the Dart: New project, I only see an error message saying (command 'dart.createProject' not found). What should I do to overcome this error!?

I tried to add a new command in command palette but I failed to add it

Comment: where are you seeing that error message? notification widget? output panel? please show what you see in the dart output channel in the output panel.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Also include the version number for your Dart extension.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your Dart-related extensions?